# Can you permanently improve movement points?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

My heroes for the final campaign have extreme differences in their movement points.  Irina has 92, Sandor 68, & Kiril 63.  I noticed they could move MUCH further at the end of campaigns then the start, but I can't figure out why.  All are lvl 30 & have the logistics & path traits, all 3 are magic heroes.

So my overall question is how that happened.  (in order to improve other heroes movements)

Answer (score 1):

Abilities like logistics, artifacts like Sandals of the Wanderer, and tagging map elements like stables or rally flags are the only move boosters I know of.  I read somewhere that heroes without units can move further than those with armies, but I haven't observed that in my own games.  Previous Heroes games set movement to the slowest unit in the army, but again I haven't noticed anything like that.  Regardless, those are impressive numbers and perhaps reflect an older version of the game.  I don't think I've ever had a hero with more than 50 movement or so, fully kitted and buffed.  One thing I *have* encountered was a mysterious and persistent 25% penalty to mana costs, but only for my avatar and 2nd hero, both brought forward from previous maps.  In a similar vein, the only thing I can think of is that some of your heroes got some kind of move boost from a "Week of the..." that, through a bug, lingered on after the week ended and/or on to the next campaign map.

Comment: Army units definiately affected H2 and H3.  I assumed the same for H4+ but not sure I ever actually confirmed it.  If I did I don't recall.

Comment: Definitely also in Heroes 4. It's the reason, why Havens Ballistae are terrible, they slow you down so much on the adventure map.

Answer (score 0):

**Type of terrain   - Amount of movement points:**

- Normal 100%
- Road 125%
- Difficult 75%
- Hard 50%
- Swamp 75%

**Bonuses:**

- Base movement points - **27**
- Ability - Logistics - +3 land
- Specialization - Explorer - +3 land+sea
- Dynasty Trait - Explorer - +3 land+sea
- Dynasty Trait - Wanderlust - Whenever the Main Hero starts their turn in a town, their movement points are increased by 6.
- Dynasty Trait - Noble Mount - The Hero's movement is increased by 5 in the first week.
- [Artefacts](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Heroes_VI_artifacts)
- Buildings - only one week bonuses

**Note:**
Units slow down hero in H6 too.

**Bug:**
"Pathfinding skill is still broken (actually adds movement PENALTY, instead of bonus on hard terrain!). I assume it was fixed for the normal campaigns, but not the expansions?"

**PS:** I will try to investigate it more and update answer.